# Salary in US for remote engineer?

Tags: job-search, salary

I currently live in Europe and I am applying  for a remote security engineer job in a US startup.

My question is simple, what salary could I expect for this kind of job?
I have 6 years of experience.
I found after some Internet researches, it is about 120/150k$ for a security engineer in US but can I hope the same for a remote job?

Thank you for any feedback.

Rob'

Comment: So this company is OK with their security expert living in a (significantly) different time zone? I find it a little strange that they wouldn't want you in a location where you could _sometimes_ go in to the office.

Comment: This is off Topic. Since this is primarly opion based and not only that salary is different between Country's on multiple factors.

Comment: That is _far_ too general a question to be answerable.  Every company is going to make their own decision about whether to pay you based on US rates of your local rates. The latter is much more likely, since otherwise it would be much simpler for them to hire someone in the US.

Comment: "I find it a little strange that they wouldn't want you in a location where you could sometimes go in to the office." Welcome to the 21st century

Comment: "So this company is OK with their security expert living in a (significantly) different time zone?" Which could be a significant advantage. Nothing better than a team around the globe so that at least one is awake and ready.

Comment: @FooBar Yeah why not? People work grave shifts all the time because they get paid better or they like it, or both.

Comment: @AndreiROM If you think about it, he can take care of late-night support in the US during normal Euro day-time hours.

Answer (score 4):

This is all simply supposition, but here goes:

- Startups are not well known for being flush with cash. Quite the contrary, actually: long hours, below market value wages.
- What possible advantage would they have to hiring a security expert (or any employee) in a different time zone? The only one I can think of is because they expect that foreign expert to cost them less to employ than a local expert.

If I were you I would lower my expectations.

Comment: Well they might also need him to be doing some of the security work during the off hours in the States or they might have other remote workers who are in other time zones and need support. Or they might be willing to accept remote workers who are in the same time zone but didn't put that in their job advertisement.

Comment: I'm not sure if I entirely agree with below market values. Many startups are trying to hire the best talent to ensure their success, so while they may not have a ton of money they are spending what they have on the right people.